# Django POST shows in form, but doesn't come through to the next view

Tags: python, django

I have a simple form such as:

```
    <form action = "{% url 'endresult' %}" form method = "POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="well">
          <h4 style="margin-top: 0"><strong> Student Details </strong></h4>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label/> Student ID
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name = "studentpost" placeholder= "{{student.studentid}}" readonly>
            </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

The student ID does show up in my form, but when I try to get the results from `endresult` it shows up as a blank, if i try to call the `studentid` i get none.  Why is this?

```
def endresult(request):
    postedstudent = request.POST.get('studentpost')
    print(f"postedstudent : {postedstudent }")
    studentid = request.POST.get('student.studentid')
    print(f"studentid : {studentid }")
return render(request, 'submitted.html')
```

Here is my output:

> postedstudent:
>      studentid: None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placeholder values are just that, placeholders. They are replaced by whatever is entered into the field, and are not submitted wth the form.

If you want a value to be prepopulated so that it is submitted, you should use the `value` attribute instead.

I have no idea why you think `request.POST.get('student.studentid')` would give a value, though.

Comment: Thank you Daniel.  I'm just exploring with code for a hobby.  I'm surely learning from my mistakes.  I threw that in for some of the other things i tried, i didn't expect it would, but i had to try.